# if $\dim(U)+\dim(W)>\dim(V)$ So $U\cap W\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let there be $U,W\subseteq V$

Prove: if $\dim(U)+\dim(W)>\dim(V)$ So $U\cap W\neq 0$

$\dim(U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U\cap W)\rightarrow \dim(U\cap W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U+W)<\dim(V)-\dim(U+W)$

Because $U,W\subseteq V\rightarrow \dim(U+V)\leq \dim(V)$

So $\dim(V)-\dim(U+W)\geq0$ How can I prove that $\dim(V)-\dim(U+W)>0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dim V\ge\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)\implies$$

$$\dim(U\cap W)\ge\dim U+\dim W-\dim V\stackrel{\text{given!}}>0$$

and w'ere done.